# Reproducir audio en otra página al presionar un botón javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy intentando reproducir un audio en una pagina al hacer click en un boton pero que esta en otra pagina, es decir, hago click en el boton de la **pagina1** y el audio se debe reproducir en la **pagina2** en tiempo real.

Hacerlo en la misma pagina es sencillo, a continuación muestro código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Prueba</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css_prueba.css">
</head>

<body>

    <audio id="audio" controls>
        <source type="audio/mp3" src="audio.mp3"><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </audio> 

    <input type="button" value="ALARMA" name="btn_alarma" id="BTN_ALARMA" onclick="alarma();"/>
</body>
</html>

<script>
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function alarma(){
    audio.play();
}
</script>
```

Y el codigo CSS para que oculte los controles del audio:

```
#audio{
display: none
}
```

Para hacerlo de **pagina1** a **pagina2** intente importar el codigo js en ambas paginas poniendo la etiqueta `<audio>` solamente en la **pagina2** y el botón "ALARMA" solo en la **pagina1** pero no funciona, y la verdad no se como hacerlo.

¿Es posible hacer esto?, si alguien tiene un ejemplo o que me pueda orientar una forma de como hacerlo estaré muy agradecido...

Answer (score 2):

Logré que al hacer clic en el botón de tu código, se reproduzca automáticamente el audio en una nueva ventana:

```css
#audio{
display: none
}
```

```html
<body>

    <audio id="audio" controls>
        <source type="audio/mp3" src="#"><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    </audio> 

    <input type="button" value="ALARMA" name="btn_alarma" id="BTN_ALARMA" onclick="window.open('audio.mp3'); return false;"/> 
  
</body>
</html>

<script>
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");

function window.open(){
    audio.play();
}
</script>
```

---

Como puedes notar cambié inicialmente el **src** por #, pues lo que se quiere es que se reproduzca en la nueva ventana. Luego con el evento `onclick="window.open('audio.mp3'); return false;"` lo que le digo al botón es que me abra en una nueva ventana el archivo o dirección "audio.mp3" y que se reproduzca automáticamente con la función `audio.play();`

---

**PD:**

Para hacer las pruebas reemplacé tu archivo "audio.mp3" por esta dirección a modo de ejemplo: http://www.evidenceaudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lyricchords.mp3

Funcionó sin problemas